# What does bash do here in this ssh command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

```
ssh -i host 'scripts/myScript start; bash'
```

where start is a function in shell script?
What does appending bash to the script does here?
A little background:
It results in an interactive shell for me and executes myScript just like actually logging into host using plain ssh would do. If i omit bash though.

```
ssh -i host 'scripts/myScript start;'
```

It doesnt result in an interactive login, but non-interactive shell login, and my myScript doesn't work as intended because of the environment variable issues.

Comment: Can you write an MCVE that demonstrates the behaviors you're seeing? Because tacking `; bash` onto the end *shouldn't* affect the execution environment of the original script. (Also, some details about the systems involved -- version of `ssh`, OS version, remote login shell, etc. -- might help.)

Answer (score 2):

The trailing `bash` will cause to start an interactive session of `bash` on the remote host after the command `scripts/myScript start` returns.

Also you need to allocate a pseudo terminal using `-t`:

```
ssh -t host 'scripts/myScript start; bash'
```

Comment: Will it be fatal if i dont use the -t option? Because even without -t it serves my purpose and using -t gives me a prompt on the local machine from where i give this command to remote host. And thats not kind of what i want.
Also, since bash is issued after myScript, how and why does myScript executes in interactive environment?

Comment: @user3814996 the bash session you are seeing while using `-t` is opened on remote computer, not your local computer..without `-t` the bash session can hang as there is no terminal to connect to on local..also ssh host 'command' runs the `command` in a non-interactive (and non-login) bash session....